# Any way to pass a value into an Experience page through the query string?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, experience-cloud, digital-experience, experience-builder-page

When I try manually adding a parameter to a Digital Experience page URL e.g. `/s/myPage?ns__abc=def` (with or without a namespace), both the `state` in the wired `CurrentPageReference` and the `window.location.search` are empty in an LWC within the page.

Embedding a Visualforce page s a component in a Digital Experience page that uses {!$CurrentPage.parameters.ns__abc} also does not work: likely the parameters are stripped out in the page logic.

(The actual need here is to be able to jump in to an Experience page with a couple of parameters passed in.)

Are such parameters completely blocked in Experiences?

Comment: Did you try `const queryParams = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams;` then `console.log(queryParams.get('ns__abc'));` ? Using it in connectedCallback should work.

Comment: Hi @RubenDG, I'm using `console.log('>>> location=' + JSON.stringify(window.location, null, 4));` which is an equivalent and does present `"search": ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure your LWCs are self-contained and reusable, you should not directly interrogate the `window.location` or page state. Instead you should arrange for your LWC to receive property values through its own API (with that API property also declared as a target property in the meta.xml).

The Experience Builder then allows you to use expressions to tie your query parameter through to an API target property.

For example, if I have a query parameter called "contactId", so the URL is like `.../s/myPage?contactId=003...`, then I can arrange for this parameter value to be passed to my LWC using the expression `{!contactId}` as the value for the relevant API target property through the component property editor.

[image: Example of a query parameter expression]

Expression variable names are either tied to named bindings in the URL for the page (like `recordId` in the generic object Record Detail page's URL `/detail/:recordId`) or from query parameters.

[image: Example of path binding]

Comment: Thanks Phil. So `{! ... }` expressions setting the value of exposed `@api` component properties allow an arbitrary query string parameters to be injected into those properties. Nice.

Comment: Yup. Either URL bindings or arbitrary query parameters. Pretty neat really. And as you can see, not limited to LWCs - my first example is actually an embedded flow with input variables.

Comment: I recall I had an issue with the strings coming in as URLEncoded for my Flow (example was the caller passing the (TM) UTF-8 character in as a param and the flow saw this as urlencoded

Comment: Hi @PhilW, So far I haven't managed to get a query string parameter in a portal page URL to make it through to a flow input variable. This is something you have working? Do you have a link to the relevant SF documentation?

Comment: The first screenshot actually shows this. The key is to ensure you set the flow's resource variable as "available as input". Check the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_resources_variable.htm&type=5) for the "available outside the flow" detail.

Comment: Importantly, to get a query variable from URL through to an LWC in the flow, first map to a flow input variable then use that flow variable to set the target property on the LWC in your flow screen.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW I'll double check my setup. This works for you in a Digital Experience (AKA Community) page right?

Comment: Yup. That is a screenshot direct from one of our DE pages. It is an Aura build your own. I have not tested with LWR (and am not sure LWR supports flows, TBH, I would need to investigate).

Comment: Thanks for all your help @PhilW. Works on first navigation to the page but repeatedly pasting the same URL into the browser (as I was doing for testing) doesn't; presumably relates to the lifecycle of the flow.

Comment: Could be. We've not noticed similar issues at this point.

Comment: Hi @PhilW, Well you are correct. The problem was caused by a navigation menu component doing a `NavigationMixin.Navigate` to the same page. (Code probably done as a quick fix for a problem...) If that got there last then no query string parameters. So marginal timing hence the varying results.