# Is there a way to create a custom domain identification for a page of each portal user

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud, identity

I am looking for a solution to create for each portal user a custom url for a specific experience cloud page. Eg. User x will access his own data on 'domain.com/s/site/customId'

Is it possible to create such a page in the builder itself or based on a custom lwc component?

Answer (score 0):

You can add variable "bindings" in a URL using syntax like `:bindingName` as part of the URL, just like you see for things like the generic record detail page (which uses `:recordId` to populate the record ID used in the record banner/details components).

This allows you to pass that value to component(s) via `{!expressions}` in their property settings.

The trick is how you generate the URL in the first place and then what you do with it later.

To generate in the digital experience, you need a custom component creating the link. Where it gets the value is for you to decide.

Read more about experience site URL variables in [this previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/401710/50252).